# List manipulation, replace a value

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
AA= {300., 150., 100., 76.8421, 64.0909, 55.567, 49.1935, 44.2262, 
    40.2247, 36.9355, 34.1667, 31.8138, 29.7887, 28.0087, 26.4537, 
    25.0612, 23.8186, 22.7059, 21.6854, 20.7663, 19.9265, 19.1519, 
    18.4323, 17.7739, 17.1672, 16.6007, 16.0648, 15.5605, 15.098}
```

If a value of AA is higher than 100, I want replace this value with a an arbitrary value, e.g. 50. Has anyone any idea how to do this?